# How can I check if previously running ProgressChanged has finished in DoWork event in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, process, backgroundworker, wait

Here is a scenario, its a winforms application where I have a collection of processes which i'm running one by one inside a for-loop in the DoWork event of Backgroundworker class. And I call ReportProgress() periodically in the for-loop to update UI.

Now when I call ReportProgress() it triggers ProgressChanged event where I have the code to update the UI with all the message I have set previously in DoWork. But as this runs in a separate thread, the control goes in parallel in DoWork, but I want to hold/wait the for-loop for sometime until the previously running ProgressChanged event.

Currently, I'm calling Thread.Sleep(1000) in for-loop before executing any operation in it (like picking up the next process and running it) and this code is giving me desired output. So I just wanted to check if there is any alternative solution where (I don't use Thread.Sleep instead) I can verify/ wait the for-loop until the previously running ProgressChanged event has finished its job, and only then I proceed to run the next process from the collection in for-loop.

Comment: Just don't do this. Switch to calling ReportProgress() more often to pump your messages to use the user, but this mechanism was never intended to keep things in perfect sync.

Comment: Use an AutoResetEvent to synchronize it.  Call its Set() method in a finally block in the event handler and WaitOne() after the ReportProgress call.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn  I can do that but, I'm appending some messages in a Stringbuilder object in DoWork and using same in ProgressChanged event. So, here while the object is being consumed in to update Ui, it gets updated in parallel in DoWork. To avoid this I wanted to introduce a delay in DoWork,
 Calling ReportProgress very often will use the stringbuilder object and update, as result it won't show the output in right order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without addressing the issues with your overall design, the way you would do this is with a [semaphore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore(v=vs.110).aspx). The most basic example would be:

```
static Semaphore _semaphore = new Semaphore(0,1);
WorkStatus _workStatus;

void DoWork()
{
    _semaphore.WaitOne();
    try
    {
        _workStatus = Foo();  //Only one thread will be able to execute this at a time
    }
    finally
    {
        _semaphore.Release();
    }
}

void HandleProgressChanged()
{
    _semaphore.WaitOne(); //Wait for any DoWork threads to finish
    try
    {
        DisplayProgress(_workStatus);
    }
    finally
    {
        _semaphore.Release();
    }
    Task.Run(DoWork);
}
```

Comment: I'm new to the Semaphore concept. But this solution looks good. Just one thing I want to know, Can this go along with Backgroundworker class?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter. Whatever c# code can access that semaphore can use it in this fashion.